# (Java) Ball bounce off paddle in realistic way

Tags: java, bounce

So I am trying to make a simple game and I need the ball to bounce off the paddle. Right now I have the ball bouncing around the window fine but it goes through the paddle and I am having trouble making it bounce off of the paddle in a realistic way. 
This is the code I have that makes the ball bounce off of the walls and it works perfectly:

```
//advance the ball
            ball.advance();
            //check if ball should bounce off canvas sides
            if(ball.getCenterX()+ ball.getRadius() > canvas.getWidth()) ball.setDirectionX(LEFT);
            if(ball.getCenterX() - ball.getRadius() <0) ball.setDirectionX(RIGHT);

            if(ball.getCenterY()+ ball.getRadius() > canvas.getHeight()) ball.setDirectionY(UPWARDS);
            if(ball.getCenterY() - ball.getRadius() < 0) ball.setDirectionY(DOWNWARDS);
```

The problem is I am not sure if I should modify these if statements or add more and I am not sure how to make the ball bounce off of the paddle properly. I tried adding a couple of if statements and the best I got was this: [GIF of game](https://gyazo.com/f91d82811e21f6eebc41f83c52913b1b) The statements I added were:

`if(ball.getCenterY()+ ball.getRadius() > paddle.getTopLeftY()) ball.setDirectionY(UPWARDS);
if(ball.getCenterY()+ ball.getRadius() < paddle.getTopLeftX()) ball.setDirectionY(DOWNWARDS);`

Thanks for any help you could give :)

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I think I have too much code to make a short runnable example/ I don't really know how because I'm using a couple of classes. I could post specific parts if it can help you to help me. The problem is I can't figure out how to set up the if statements so that the ball will bounce off of the paddle and go up or hit the bottom if it misses the paddle. With just the first chunk of code that I posted it looks like this: https://gyazo.com/7b51794a6e5e474b508cf442ddebc8dc The ball bounces around the window find but goes right through the paddle and im trying to figure out hot to get it to to bounce.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the ball to bounce when **both X and Y** coordinates reach the paddle.

Right now, you are just using `ball.getCenterY()+ ball.getRadius() > paddle.getTopLeftY()`, so it does not matter if the ball is near the paddle in the `X` axis.

Try with something like this.

(you might need to adjust the `<` and `>` depending on whether the values for `X` increase or decrease when moving from left to right)

```
boolean bounceInY = ball.getCenterY()+ ball.getRadius() > paddle.getTopLeftY();
boolean bounceInX = (ball.getCenterX()+ ball.getRadius() > paddle.getTopLeftX()) && (ball.getCenterX()+ ball.getRadius() < paddle.getTopLeftX() + paddle.getWidth());
if (bounceInY && bounceInX) ball.setDirectionY(UPWARDS);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything when this code is added(I messed with the < and > too). Still goes right through paddle: https://gyazo.com/d1b30c91e6485e9d24c85d1682fd50a3 However, what I tried is adding this line : if (ball.getCenterY() + ball.getRadius() > paddle.getTopLeftY() && ball.getCenterY() + ball.getRadius() < paddle.getTopLeftX() + paddle.getWidth())
                    ball.setDirectionY(UPWARDS);
and it works a little bit but not consistently. It seems to bounce off the paddle one time and the next time it goes right through. Any thoughts?

Comment: From your code it seems you use "paddle.getTopLeftX() + paddle.getWidth()" instead of having a "paddle.getTopRightX()". I am modifying my answer to use that same structure. Perhaps it works that way..

Comment: Ok it is starting to bounce off of the paddle now with your code: https://gyazo.com/0ad8c31942a308d7ba39e001b419b66e but it is a bit glitchy as in the ball seems to bounce from under the paddle sometimes and from the top sometimes. Also when it misses it doesn't seem to reach the bottom of the window anymore it bounces before it gets to the bottom.

Comment: That might have to do with how much you are increasing the X and Y coordinate of the ball in each cycle. Try making the steps smaller. I don't think I can help you much more given the scope of your answer, perhaps you should post a new question with this new problem and include more code.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help! I am going to take a break and try to figure it out tomorrow.